# Django Haystack - No module named 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch5_backend'

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

Im following the install instructions as per the haystack documentation 
http://docs.haystacksearch.org/en/master/tutorial.html#installation and the search engine installation https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/installing_search_engines.html#elasticsearch

I have installed Elasticsearch 5.1.16 which is listed as compatible and have put the settings in, the installation guide only has examples for Elasticsearch versions 1 and 2 but states that 5 is supported.

so I changed to version 5 in the settings

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch5_backend.Elasticsearch5SearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

I have also gone through the repo and can see that version 5 is in there

[image]

but when I start my server I receive the error:

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch5_backend'
```

but then when I traverse the folder structure it hasn't installed the version 5 files

```
root@4c1197e002e8:/myapp/# ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/haystack/backends/
__init__.py                __pycache__/               elasticsearch2_backend.py  elasticsearch_backend.py   simple_backend.py          solr_backend.py            whoosh_backend.py
```

and im using the same version as the git repo that has the 5 backend in it?

root@4c1197e002e8:/myapp/# pip freeze | grep hay
django-haystack==2.8.1

EDIT:
its also already installed into my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'haystack',
...
```

anyone help me out whats missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a `pip install git+https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack` and now the `version5` backend is in there.

Answer (score 1):

I was using pipenv:

```
pipenv install git+https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack.git#egg=django-haystack
```

A modification of AlexW's answer worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'haystack' in your installed app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',

# Added.
'haystack',

# Then your usual apps...
'blog',
```

]

Comment: it already is, just edited to show. I think the problem is that the elasticsearch5_backend is missing from the installed package on my container, and im not sure why as its clearly seen on the GitHub repo

Comment: I think I got it, I think the git repo is a development version? I just did a pip install git+https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack and now the version5 backend is in there